# Why is Google Chrome mobile device emulator showing my 320 pixel wide site as it is?

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I've added media queries to my website so that the pages display at a width of 300 pixels, if the "max-width" of a user's browser is less than 480 pixels.

My question is this: When I view the pages using Google Chrome's device emulator - and the emulator quite clearly says that the width for the Apple iPhone 6 is "375" pixels wide, why does my 300 pixel wide website display at a much narrower width (about 100 pixels)?

I'm confused because when I view the website via my standard PC browser and reduce the width of the browser - everything is fine. When I use the emulator, even though it specifies that Apple iPhone 6 has resolution of 375 pixels, why do the web pages shrink to about 100 pixels wide?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you included the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in your page header?

Comment: life saver. this was missing in 1 page... so was looking in CSS instead of HTML